# When should the Visual Studio tags be used?

Tags: support, tags

I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470235/c-sharp-transparent-trackbar-using-controlstyles) which is tagged [visual-studio-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012), but the question doesn't seem to have to do anything with that product other than (I suppose) it is used to code the application the user is working on.

I was under the impression that tags like `visual-studio-xxxx` are supposed to be used when you are working on something relevant, e.g. a plug-in for VS, or when your question involves a feature of VS. Looking through the other questions in this category I see similar questions, so I'm wondering what the exact policy is?

Comment: The question also doesn't have anything to do with the C# language.  They are *contextual* tags.  Generally useful to provide context and attract experts that are familiar with the tooling, not required.  Note that [visual-studio] would be useless but [visual-studio-2012] is good.

Comment: This happens a lot with Xcode, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio is completely irrelevant to the problem and as such I removed the tag. It's the classic example of someone new to programming that uses the tags to indicate their IDE and often several other aspects of code like [for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for) or [while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/while) when that has nothing to do with the question.

I disagree with @Peter M's position that you should leave it in because it *might* be a problem. But by definition: if you should always leave it in because it might be appropriate, that means every single question should be tagged with it or you'd have to be arrogant enough to assume you know everything.

If after the question has been answered it has been deemed that the IDE tag is appropriate after all, you should add it back of course.

Use the general [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) when the question is about Visual studio and not just because you happen to use Visual studio. Add a second, more specific version tag like [visual-studio-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012) if you have a question specific to that version.

PS: note that the question in itself is also a bad one

> Please someone show me a step by step guide on changing this bit value for my trackbar. I have tried to copy&paste the example to my Form1.cs but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Many times the functionality available to solve a software problem when using VS is dependent on the version of VS being used.   And when new functionality is added it is not necessarily back-ported to previous VS versions.

For example yesterday I was just reading up on Entity Framework and saw that support for it was introduced in VS2008 and with each following version (VS2010, VS2012, VS2013 etc) more functionality was added.  So if someone posted an EF question, the roadmap to their solution would depend on the version of VS that they had.

However I don't know enough about WinForms to ascertain if the VS tag was warranted for that particular question.

Comment: I agree that it helps if users mention their version of VS and the OS they're working on and the target of their development etc., but I don't feel those should be tags. They are possibly relevant to the question, but they're not the [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) of the question.

Comment: @BCdotNET Tool and OS version *can* affect relevancy of the solutions, as such you can't make a definitive statement about them without parsing and understanding both the question and solution.  At least by making them tags you can better slice and dice search results when looking for a solution.

Comment: If you have a specific reason to expect that the OS or IDE is the problem, then by all means add them.  If you don't, then adding them actually makes SO worse off by making people who really do have version specific problems have difficulty searching for answers to their problems.  Remember that if it does turn out to be an issue with your version you can always add the tag later.